# php variable after a variable in for loop

Tags: php

I need a way to do this

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
$id$i = "example" . $i;
}
```

notice the second line has $id$i
so for the first loop $id1 will equal example1
in the second loop $id2 will equal example2
and so on...
Thank you very much!

Comment: That's what arrays are for, is there a reason you can't use an array?

Comment: i have tryed $id[1]= "example" . $i; but its not working.
i think the syntax is wrong

Comment: It is possible using variable variables, but not recommended: http://ideone.com/gjvIX.

Comment: Just initialize the array before your loop and use `$id[$i] = "example" . $i` in the loop

Comment: the syntax would be $id[$i] instead of $id[1].  What you tried would be putting each string in position 1 of the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [variable variable names](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to do this; however, it's probably much more convenient if you just used an array:

```
for($i = 1, $i <= 10, $i++) {
    $id[] = "example" . $i;
}
```

Comment: what should be inside the []?

Comment: Nothing. `$id[]` means append to the end of array `$id`.

Comment: Note that array indices start from 0; if you REALLY want the indices to start from 1, you can use `$id[$i]` in this particular case instead.

Comment: I know about arrays i just aint knew that [] means the end of the array. thank you! it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string into a variable (the name of the variable), if you put another `$` in front of it:

```
$str = "number";
$number = 5;
$$str = 8;
echo $number;  // will output 8
```

So in your example, you could do it like that:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $str_var = "id".$i;
    $$str_var = "example".$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to use an array, but you *could* do this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    $var ="id$i";
    $$var = "example" . $i;
}
```

Here's what I would recommend doing instead:

```
$ids = array;
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $ids[$i] = "example" . $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of size `$i` with a name of `$id`, and insert each element into a different index.

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
    $id[$i] = "example" . $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array();
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
$var['id' . $i] = 'example' . $i;
}
extract($var, EXTR_SKIP);
unset($var);
```

but why not use a simple array?